# Сделать background во flask, если использую bootstrap

Tags: html, css, flask

Не могу никак растянуть картинку на весь экран. И не очень понимаю, как это корректно сделать в flask.
Вот код, css подключаю в index, получается,что весь контент не на картинке, а над ней(((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: url(static/images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    {% block css %}
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock %}

        <title>
        {% block title %}
            Base
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="parrent">
      {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg') }}" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задаёте изображению position: absolute и оно не будет занимать место.
Если вдруг будет перекрывать контент, можно дописать z-index: -1;
И ещё я так понял вы задний фон создаёте в html, чтобы можно было при желании через админку поменять изображение?
Если нет, тогда лучше выводить через css и не париться.

```css
.parrent {
  position: relative;
}
.parrent > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но, к сожалению, это не срабатывает. В html задаю background, т.к. если просто в css прописываю путь к картинке  и подключаю свои стили в базовом шаблоне, это не отрисовывается(. Не понимаю, как это исправить во flask, тут все как-то по-другому.

Comment: Не правильно путь к картинке прописываете значит.

Comment: .parrent {
  position: relative;
}

.parrent > img {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
Картинка лежит static/css/images.
По пути   background: url(static/images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg);
аналогично.

Comment: а style.css лежит в "static/css/style.css", а картинка в "static/css/images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg". Значит будет "background: url('/images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg') no-repeat, center;". И если стилями задаёте изображение, тогда нужно давать его .parrent и убрать position, а не <img>. <img> тогда вообще не нужно.

Comment: .parrent {
  position: absolute;
  background: url("/images/1618002999_34-p-oboi-zhiraf-36.jpg") no-repeat, center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
не сработало

Comment: В общем Вы были правы, насчет того, что неверно указаываю путь картинки: нужно было явно прописать путь templates при инициализации приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было: явно прописать путь templates при инициализации приложения: app = Flask(**name**, static_url_path='/')
Ответ нашла здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864209/how-to-specify-the-location-of-an-image-in-css-in-python-flask